# Incompatible types for CrudRepository with multiple types

Tags: java, spring-boot, ternary-operator

I'm working on web application where you can manage students and teachers. Both of these are classes and have a `Person` as their superclass.

I'm using Spring Boot and for both classes i'm using the `CrudRepository` for retrieving data. Both have use a `Long` type for their primary key.

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {
   
}

public interface TeacherRepository extends CrudRepository<Teacher, Long> {
            
}
```

I'm working on retrieving the currently logged in user, where I want to do something like this, so I only have to call the `findOne` method once.

```
//Person
Person activePerson = activeUser.getPerson();

// Find the id from the active user
long activePersonId = activePerson.getId();

//Find the corresponding crudrepository
CrudRepository<Person, Long> repository = activePerson instanceof Student ? studentRepository : teacherRepository;
return repository.findOne(activePersonId);
```

When using this, I'm getting the error:

> Incompatible types. Required `CrudRepository <Person, java.lang.Long>`. Found `StudentRepository`
>
> Incompatible types. Required `CrudRepository <Person, java.lang.Long>`. Found `TeacherRepository`

How does this come, since they do both have the same superclass?

For my own attempt, I tried removing the generic tags from the `repisitory` variable like this:

```
CrudRepository repository = activePerson instanceof Student ? studentRepository : teacherRepository;
return repository.findOne(activePersonId);
```

This also resulted in a Incompatible types error.

> Incompatible types. Requried `Person`. Found `java.

How does this come and how can I make it so I can make a generic variable for the specific `CrudRepository` I want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the generics do not match. If you only want to allow implementations of `Person`, you should properly write your generic as `? extends Person`:

```java
CrudRepository<? extends Person, Long> repository = activePerson instanceof Student ? studentRepository : teacherRepository;
```

Though personally I would probably write:

```java
if (activePerson instanceof Student) {
    return studentRepository.findOne(activePerson.getId());
} else {
    return teacherRepository.findOne(activePerson.getId());
}
```